# How to conditionally remove validation for a specific key in a object in Joi Schema?

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm using Joi for JSON schema validation, and I need to remove validation for a specific key (id) in a simple object within the main schema.

Here's a example of my existing schema:

```
const schema = Joi.object({
  id: Joi.string().required(),
  operation: Joi.string().required(),
  // Other keys...
});
```

I attempted to create a new schema (newSchema) by using the .keys() method to remove the validation for the id key, similar to this:

```
const newSchema = schema.concat(Joi.object({
  id: Joi.any().optional(), // Attempted approach
}));
```

However, this approach doesn't seem to work as intended.

I want to achieve a new schema that is the same as the original but without the validation for the id key:

How can I remove the validation for the id key in a simple object using Joi?

Comment: `this approach doesn't seem to work as intended.` What happens exactly?

Comment: The validation for id remains the same. if i send a not string value for `id` it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know which types you are going through, you can use the alternatives (link to the doc [here](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#alternatives))

So, if you would like to have string or integer numbers as id, you could do something like

```
const schema = Joi.object({
 id: Joi.alternatives().try(Joi.number(), Joi.string()).required(),
 operation: Joi.string().required(),
  // Other keys...
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @stefano. 
but the base schema is not under my control. Its part of the different library. I want to extend it for my usecase in my module. so i cannot change the base schema with alternatives function.

Answer (score 0):

The overriding works when using [.keys](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.9.1#objectkeysschema)

```
const newSchema = schema.keys({
  id: Joi.any().optional()
});
```